# añadir fragmento de codigo html con "include" a plantilla adminLTE laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, adminlte

Tengo la siguiente duda, tengo lo siguiente en un archivo `.blade.php`

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{session()->get('success')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

y recientemente implemente la plantilla adminLTE con el package de [jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE), mi pregunta es, existe alguna forma de añadir atraves de un `include` este archivo .blade a la  plantilla general de adminLte?, quiero intentar evitar añadir el include en todas mis plantillas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer para poder editar las plantillas predefinidas de Laravel-AdminLTE es hacer públicas las vistas, eso lo puedes hacer con el comando:

```
$ php artisan adminlte:install --only=main_views
```

Una vez hecho esto, verás en el folder `/resources/views/vendor/adminlte` las templates. Luego solo debés agregar tu include donde corresponda.

Para ver la documentación de la wiki de jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE sobre como customizar las vistas, puedes verlo aquí:
https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Views-Customization